# Is TLS-level compression with Apache possible?

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, compression, http

Apache2 can transfer compressed data by using the deflate filter. However, it does a HTTP-level compression: it sends back a compressed response, and it shows in the response headers to the clients to deal with it accordingly.

However, not this is what I want.

Beside the https-level compression, also TLS has a compression functionality (for example, [here](https://tls.mbed.org/api/ssl_8h.html#abf3d629fb7b9263db5c3cfbe6a2b6089) is it visible in the mbedtls API).

Can I set up somehow Apache to compress the SSL transfers with it, and not on the http level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ( for production );

> Chrome and Firefox have removed support for TLS compression in their most recent updates.

https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2012/09/14/crime-information-leakage-attack-against-ssltls

But if you just want to play;

> SSLCompression on

https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2012/september/details-on-the-crime-attack/

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcompression

Comment: I am sorry, but this CRIME thing looks real security paranoia to me. Fact is, contrary the so-named "crime", compression is an inherent part of any secure, encrypted communication and not a security hole. Furthermore, my clients are embedded devices programmed by me. But thanks! Somehow this "SSLCompression" flag has avoided my eyes. :-)